# Flask/SQLAlchemy - WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: sqlalchemy

How could I translate this:

```
SELECT id, 
FROM user
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM user_agency_assoc 
                  WHERE user.ID = user_agency_assoc.user_id)
AND user.invited_by IS NOT NULL
```

as an SQLAlchemy ORM query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this,

```
db.session.query(user.id)
.filter(
    ~user_agency_assoc.query
    .filter(user.id == user_agency_assoc.user_id)
    .exists()
)
```

assuming your corresponding model names are `user` and `user_agency_assoc`

Comment: This does not seem to select columns. It produces `WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM _table_ WHERE _filter_)`. What if one would like to have `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT _column_ FROM _table_ WHERE _filter_)`?

Comment: `EXISTS` reduces to a boolean, so what the subquery returns is irrelevant. All that matters is whether the query matched a record or not.