# SQLAlchemy query parents with ALL children matching a filter

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a sqlalchemy query (flask-sqlalchemy) that only returns parent objects if ALL children match the query instead of ANY. IE

```
(Parent
 .query
 .join(Child)
 .filter(Child.column == True)
 ).all()
```

Will return all of the parent objects that have any child with `column == True`, how do I write it so that all children must have `column == True`?

### ------------------------------- update ------------------------------

The above portion was abstracted from this actual code. Where

Parent == Student and Child == StudentApplication

The model heirarchy goes:

User ---> Students ---> StudentApplication

I'm trying to retrieve users, who have students, who's application has not been submitted, while ignoring users who have at least 1 student with a submitted application.

```
def _active_student_query(statement=None):
    import sqlalchemy as sa
    statement = statement or _active_user_query()
    statement = statement.join(Student).filter(Student.suspended == sa.false())
    return statement

def users_without_submitted_applications(exclude_contacted=False):
    import sqlalchemy as sa
    from sqlalchemy.orm.util import AliasedClass

# AppAlias = AliasedClass(StudentApplication)

has_any_approved_app = sa.exists(
    sa.select([])
        .select_from(Student)
        .where((StudentApplication.student_id == Student.id) &
               (StudentApplication.flags.op('&')(AppFlags.SUBMITTED) > 0),
               )
)

statement = _active_student_query()
statement = (statement
             # .join(StudentApplication)
             # .filter(User.students.any())
             # has a student and no submitted applications
             .filter(~has_any_approved_app)
             # .filter(StudentApplication.flags.op('&')(AppFlags.SUBMITTED) == 0)
             )
if exclude_contacted:
    statement = (statement
                 .join(AlertPreferences)
                 .filter(AlertPreferences.marketing_flags.op('&')(MarketingFlags.NO_APP_PING) == 0)
                 )

from lib.logger import logger
logger.info(statement.sql)
return statement
```

And here's the SQL that it produces

```
SELECT users.is_active, users.flags, users.created_on, users.updated_on, users.id
FROM users JOIN student ON users.id = student.user_id 
WHERE users.is_active = true AND student.suspended = false AND NOT (EXISTS (SELECT  
FROM student_application 
WHERE student_application.student_id = student.id AND (student_application.flags & %(flags_1)s) > %(param_1)s))
```

Comment: So you only want parent objects with one child where that child matches your (one) condition?

Comment: @GordThompson ideally I like to be able to apply other filters to it as well, but I would like to filter out parents that have any child where the value is False

Comment: Ah, okay. More like `SELECT * FROM parent WHERE ... AND parent.id NOT IN (SELECT child.parent_id FROM child WHERE child.column = False)` ...?

Comment: @GordThompson yeah I think that would work, I was toying around with the sqlalchemy `all_` function trying to make a subquery that worked. No luck so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for a parent where all children have `column = TRUE`, then that is equivalent to all parents where no child has `column = FALSE`. If you use a JOIN, you'd run into the problem of having one row per child, instead of per parent. Therefore, I'd recommend using `WHERE EXISTS()` instead. A query like this would solve the problem:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM parent
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT
    FROM child
    WHERE child.parent_id = parent.id
      AND child.column = FALSE
)
```

and in Flask-SQLAlchemy this becomes:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
has_any_false_children = sa.exists(
  sa.select([])
  .select_from(Child)
  .where((Child.parent_id == Parent.id) &
         (Child.column == sa.false()))
)

Parent.query.filter(~has_any_false_children)
```

---

**Update**

Since you're talking about `User`s where all `Student`s have all `StudentApplication`s completed, I think it should become

```
student_has_any_non_approved_app = sa.exists(
    sa.select([])
      .select_from(StudentApplication)
      .where((StudentApplication.student_id == Student.id) &
             (StudentApplication.flags.op('&')(AppFlags.SUBMITTED) > 0) &
             ((StudentApplication.flags.op('&')(AppFlags.APPROVED) == 0) |
              (StudentApplication.flags.op('&')(AppFlags.PARTIALLY_APPROVED) == 0)))
)

user_has_any_non_approved_students = sa.exists(
    sa.select([])
      .select_from(Student)
      .where((Student.user_id == User.id) &
                         (Student.suspended == sa.false()) &
             student_has_any_non_approved_app)
)

statement = (
        _active_user_query()
        .filter(User.students.any())
      # has a student and no submitted applications
      .filter(~user_has_any_non_approved_students)
)
```

This will return all users. If you then want the students of that user, I'd put that into a separate query - and apply marketing flags there as well.

```py
statement = Student.query.filter(
    Student.user_id.in_(user_ids),
    Student.suspended == sa.false()
)

if exclude_contacted:
    statement = (statement
                 .join(AlertPreferences)
                 .filter(AlertPreferences.marketing_flags.op('&')(MarketingFlags.NO_APP_PING) == 0)
                 )
```

Comment: It looks good, I'm just running into an issue creating an alias for the subquery. sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) subquery in FROM must have an alias
LINE 2: FROM (SELECT Child.name...
^
HINT: For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.

Comment: The subquery inside the EXISTS shouldn't need an alias, because it's not in the FROM - and your code didn't mention any other subqueries. Can you show your code? Preferably by adding it to your question so you can format it

Comment: Hey thanks for all your help. I've added the actual code to my question.

Comment: You're welcome! I have a few remarks about your code. 1) I remember having problems with `== False` - are you sure it shouldn't be `== sa.false()` or just `~Student.suspended`? 2) What is the operator `&` for - are you doing bitwise operations or did you mean something else? 3) You should not join on `StudentApplication` to prevent having multiple rows. Remove the join and move the `SUBMITTED` check to inside `has_any_approved_app`. 4) Replacing `.filter(Student.query.filter(~has_any_approved_app))` with `.filter(~has_any_approved_app)` should fix it I think

Comment: I updated the code with your recommendations and added the sql that sqlalchemy is generating. The query is still returning users if they have ANY student that matches rather than ALL students. Regarding the bitwise & operator, that was intentional.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood then. I thought you didn't want to return students with ANY unfinished applications, but you're talking about users, who can have multiple students. I'll update my answer

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the lesson!

Comment: No problem, happy to help!

Comment: @here I have situation where I need all Students those do not have StudentApplications.

I  tried `Student.filter(Students.id, StudentApplication.student_id).outerjoin(StudentApplication)`

But still getting students having StudentApplications.

Comment: I'd look into [WHERE NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38701466/5015356). Hope this helps, if you need more context, please ask a new question and link it here. I'll try to answer it in more detail